# How to use tail but ignore subdirectories in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command

I'm using `tail` in Ubuntu to fetch information from a ubuntu device. I'm kind of new to Linux so the command I use is

```
root@mydevice:/# tail /path/to/directory/*/*
```

So I can fetch many files at once.

However, some of the subdirectories also contain subdirectories, so the output looks like this:

```
==> /path/to/directory/number_one/subdirectory<==
tail: error reading '/path/to/directory/number_one/subdirectory': Is a directory

==> /path/to/directory/number_one/data_one <==
23300000

==> /path/to/directory/number_one/data_two <==
23953

==> /path/to/directory/number_one/data_three <==
667

etc...
```

Is there a way to use `tail` while ignoring subdirectories so I don't get this error?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You could just ignore the errors with `2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` and use the `-f` option so it only finds regular files, no directories. `-maxdepth 1` keeps it from recursing into the subdirectories.

```
find /path/to/sensor/*/* -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec tail {} +
```